# File submission using ajax and jquery not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file

I have to **submit the form using ajax**. The form contain a `text field` and a `file upload field`.But in `ajax page(formaction.php)` the the `file details are not getting.`

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" id="newform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Name:<input type="text" id="txt" name="txt"><br>
  File:<input type="file" id="image" name="image"><br>
  <input type="submit" id="btn" value='Proceed'>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formdata = $('form#newform').serialize();
        $.post("formaction.php",{formdata:formdata},function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

**formaction.php**

```
print_r($_REQUEST['formdata']);
```

`input type file` details are not getting in `ajax` page. The `formdata` only contain the value of text field.

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-upload-file-using-php-and-ajax-beginner-guide/

Answer (score 0):

To get file details,

instead of this,

```
print_r($_REQUEST['formdata']);
```

add this

```
print_r($_FILES['image']);
```

Comment: Error..undefined index `image`

Answer (score 0):

your jquery must be change same as this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm() {
        console.log("submit event");
        var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("fileinfo"));
        fd.append("label", "WEBUPLOAD");
        $.ajax({
          url: "formaction.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: fd,
          enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
          processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
          contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
        }).done(function( data ) {
            console.log("PHP Output:");
            console.log( data );
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `serialize()` won't include the file input in the form data. You have to do it manually.

```
$("#btn").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form_data = new FormData(document.getElementById('newform'));

    // Now you have your DataObject setup.
    $.ajax({
        url: 'formaction.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache : false,
        contentType: false, // Important.
        processData: false, // Important.
        data: form_data
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    return false;
});
```

Using `$.ajax()` you can achieve this very easily.

Now in formaction.php: You can pick up the values like normal form submission.

```
$txt = $_POST['txt'];
$image = $_FILES['image'];
```

Note: Do keep in mind those `contentType: false` and `processData: false`

If you don't give `processData: false` then ajax will return an error in the console `"Illegal invocation."`

If you don't give `contentType: false` then the file will be submitted in encoded and raw with `content-disposition` and `content-type: 'application/pdf'` or whatever mime type you are uploading.